# How to use predicates in swift?

Tags: swift, nspredicate

can anybody explain me how i can use **predicates** in **swift** or there are some batter way to do the same for nested dictionary and array of dictionaries?

I have a array of nested dictionaries in my programme and need to filter by different keys or in same cases need to filter with multiple keys so please provide me a batter solution in swift where i can filter it like NSPredicate do in objective-c

for example, I have a array of employees from the following json-

```
[{
    "name": "programmer",
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "group": "A",
    "epmloyement": {
        "complany": "abc",
        "salary": 20000
    }
},
{
    "name": "designer",
    "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
    "group": "A",
    "epmloyement": {
        "complany": "zyz",
        "salary": 25000
    }
},
{
    "name": "tester",
    "email": "aaa@gmail.com",
    "group": "B",
    "epmloyement": {
        "complany": "xxx",
        "salary": 15000
    }
}]
```

And i want following results-
if i want array of dictionaries where employee get salary greater than 2000
or if i want array of dictionaries where employee whose group = A
or if i want array of dictionaries where employee whose group = A and salary > 2000

Comment: Well, nothing stops you from using the objective c API in swift, so just use `NSPredicate`!

Comment: but if some other batter way available in swift then i will choose swift api for the same.

Comment: @DineshKumarVyas You need to show some example of what you have tried and what is your expected result

Comment: @NiravD I have updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any Objective C apis in swift.

```
 var resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c]%@",searchText)
 filteredArray = arrayToFIlter.filtered(using: resultPredicate)



1) NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", demoText)

//ARRAY
2) NSPredicate(format: "name = %@ AND nickName = %@", argumentArray: [name, nickname])


// IF CONTAINS
3)NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] %@", demoText)

//ARRAY
4) NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] %@ AND nickName contains[c] %@", argumentArray: [name, nickname])
```

Well try array `filter:` method as well

```
let digits = [1,4,10,15]
let even = digits.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }
// [4, 10]
```

Its quite intuitive and less code after all, more swifty type.

> YOUR QUERY:

```
//salary greater than 2000
a)let filteredArray =  arrayDemo.filter({(($0["epmloyement"] as! Dictionary<String,Any>)["salary"] as! Int) > 2000})

//group = A and salary > 2000
b)let fa = arrayDemo.filter({(($0["epmloyement"] as! Dictionary<String,Any>)["salary"] as! Int) > 2000 && ($0["group"] as! String) == "A"})
```

Comment: I have updated my question and is there any filter syntax which can give me  there result i am expecting?

Comment: I recommend using `filter` as well. Think of it as applying a function that takes an object and returns a `Bool`: `employees.filter { employee -> Bool in
    return employee.group == "A"
        && employment.salary >= 2000
}`

Comment: @Dinesh Kumar Vyas did it help you

Answer (score 1):

Filter your array using following

```
var filterArray = dicArray.filter { dic in
  guard let epmloyement = dic["epmloyement"] as? [String: Any] else {
    return false
  }
  guard let group = dic["group"] as? String else {
    return false
  }

  if let salary = epmloyement["salary"] as? Int {
    if (group == "A") && salary > 2000 {
      return true
    }
  }

  return false
}
```